# Images won't show after upload to Droppages

Tags: html, css, file-upload, filepath

I recently tried using Droppages as a host for my website but it won't show my images and audio, etc. 
I put the HTML-file in the 'Content'-folder and all the other files in the 'Public'-folder. 
I've tried putting the images directly into the 'Content'-folder(rather than for example Content/images/image.jpg) and also changing the pathway in several ways.

In conclusion, the website registers my code and applies all functions, but it can't find the images. Why?

Thankful for any help!

Comment: check the file permission..

Comment: All permissions are set to read only, should it be read and write?

Comment: ya you should to given it 644 or read and write.